# Installing Eric IDE on 18.04

Tags: software-installation

The reviews in the Ubuntu Software app for the Eric IDE cite install problems in recent Ubuntu versions.  Has anyone successfully installed it from the Software app in 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

I see that simple installation of Eric package with `sudo apt install eric` was not enough. So I reported [bug 1816671](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eric/+bug/1816671) about this.

Then I analyzed the error-log. It mentions `No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'`.
This python3 module came from `python3-setuptools` package.
So we need to install this package manually:

```
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
```

and then launch Eric and enjoy it.