# Installing Eric IDE in 22.04?

Tags: python, 22.04, ide

I installed Eric6 IDE from the repository in 22.04 with

```
 sudo apt install eric
```

It installed without error, but it does not start. The suggestion from [Installing Eric IDE on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119380/installing-eric-ide-on-18-04) did not help.

The error from the log is

```
 File "/usr/share/eric/modules/E5Gui/ESToolButton.py", line 55
 setPixelSize(self,int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Did anyone successfully start this package on 22.04?

Answer (score 1):

I made these changes and it got eric6 to start up. I don't know if there will be any unexpected side effects.

line 55 in /usr/share/eric/modules/E5Gui/E5ToolButton.py

this line:`font.setPixelSize(self.__badgeLabel.height() / 2.5)`

changed to:`font.setPixelSize(round(self.__badgeLabel.height() / 2.5))`

line 75 in /usr/share/eric/modules/Network/IRC/IrcWidget.py

this line: `self.splitter.setSizes([height * 0.6, height * 0.4])`

changed to: `self.splitter.setSizes([round(height * 0.6), round(height * 0.4)])`

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/7DeBR3OS9_A

it seems that there are wrong dependencies, eric7 should be installed instead of eric6

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1291995)